# How do I get my JavaScript variable to be seen by HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to code a website, but when I run my code it says function dothing() is not defined. Even though I define it in the JavaScript before I make the button that calls the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dothing(p1, p2) {
        window.open(document."https://grabify.link/VQTHDG", '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click me please. It won’t install a virus or a keylogger" onclick=dothing() >
```

Don’t ask why the function opens a grabify link (IP address logger).

Comment: Remove the "document." after the window.open. Your code already tells you an error in every validator. Next time please try a code validator beforehand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to JavaScript too.
I found three mistakes in your code:

1. remove "document". There isn't any meaning to use it
2. the semicolon missing in the function statement
3. there need to be quotation marks around dothing()

So the correct code should be like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dothing() {
        window.open("https://grabify.link/VQTHDG", '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click me please. It won’t install a virus or a keylogger" onclick="dothing()" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is broken, so the browser can't interpret the function correctly.  This has you calling `document.<string>` which isn't right I think.

```
window.open(document."https://grabify.link/VQTHDG", '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')
```

Should that be

```
window.open("https://grabify.link/VQTHDG", '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')
```

?

It's a good idea to keep the browser dev tools console open.  *If* you had, you would have seen this *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string* referencing the problem line.

Despite failing to interpret the function, the browser does its best to carry on anyway.  But, when you call that function, it doesn't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "return":

```
<input type="button" value="Click me please. It won’t install a virus or a keylogger" onclick= return dothing() >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete 'document'.
I think it should be like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dothing(p1, p2) {
        window.open("https://grabify.link/VQTHDG", '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Re *"Try to delete 'document'"*: And the full stop after it?

Comment: yes. And also the function call in your html should be quoted like user JumHorn said: 
```
<input type="button" value="Click me please. It won’t install a virus or a keylogger" onclick="dothing()" />
```